# What's the CONFIG_OF in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I see that it is being widely used at many places but could not understand in what scenarios I need to use it.

1. What is **CONFIG_OF**?
2. What is the full name of "OF"?

Comment: `OF` should be `Open Firmware`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open Firmware. This was invented long time ago when Apple was producing laptops based on PowerPC CPUs and Sun Microsystems workstations were still popular. Open Firmware provides a good description of the devices connected to the platform. In Linux kernel the part that works with device data is called Device Tree (DT). More details in the [Usage model](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/usage-model.txt).