# Where CONFIG_OF is defined in linux kernel source

Tags: linux-kernel

I saw many files with `#ifdef CONFIG_OF`. My concern is *where `CONFIG_OF` is defined*. I searched many header files but it's vain.

Comment: It's probabably specified when compiling using something like `-DCONFIG_OF`.

Comment: It's derived from the kernel configuration parameters saved in the **.config** file, which is produced by `make menuconfig`.  That **.config** file is then turned into a header file, typically called **include/generated/autoconf.h**, that can be used by the C preproccesor.

Comment: It is defined as @sawdust noted in the *.config* file, though user can't select it manually. Thus, correction to the above: it's **selected** by the architecture code which supports OpenFirmware interface.

Comment: Also good to check macros `IS_ENABLED()` and `IS_BUILTIN()`.

Comment: what: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978709/whats-the-config-of-in-linux